# Django DetailView count increases by 3 instead of 1

Tags: python, html, django

I have a webpage where every view is being counted by and incremented by 3 where it is intended to be incremented by 1 instead

here's what I have in my views.py

```
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
class MovieDetail(DetailView):
    model = Movie

    def get_object(self):
        object = super(MovieDetail, self).get_object()
        object.views_count += 1
        object.save()
        return object

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(MovieDetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['links'] = MovieLink.objects.filter(movie=self.get_object())
        context['related_movies'] = Movie.objects.filter(category=self.get_object().category)
        return context
```

## html

```
<section class="movie">
                    <img src="{{object.image.url}}">
                    <ul>
                        <li>{{object}}</li>
                        <li>{{object.description}}</li>
                        <li><a href="genre.html">Adventure</a>, <a href="genre.html">Drama</a>, <a href="genre.html">Romance</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">{{object.cast}}</a></li>
                        <li><i class="fa fa-eye" id="eye"></i> {{object.views_count}}</li>
                    </ul>
                </section>
```

It is planned to increment by 1 but does not follow that logic.. what went wrong here?

Comment: Add print(object.views_count) before the increment, my guess is that is being call more than once. Try do the incrementing one the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`get_object()` might get called more than once when your view is processed.
You could for example move the code to the `render_to_response()` method. Also make sure to increment database fields using [F() expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions).

```
from django.db.models import F


class MovieDetail(DetailView):
    model = Movie

    def render_to_response(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object.views_count = F('views_count') + 1
        self.object.save()
        return super().render_to_response(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: It now returns the following `F(views_count) + Value(1)` instead of the view count

Comment: Just moving it to `render_to_response` was fine.. I kept the value `self.object.views_count += 1` 
It did work, thankyou!

Comment: Well incrementing like this won't work if you have concurrent requests. Imagine the object in the database gets updated by another request before your method calls the `save()` method then you would overwrite the new value in the database. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/expressions/#avoiding-race-conditions-using-f

Comment: I you want to update the value in the db as described above you could add an `self.objects.refresh_from_db()` to get the new value.

Comment: I appreciate the extra mile you went through!